# For image Aspect ratio calculation image is getting loaded 2 times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

I'm trying to solve image is loading 2 times for a single preview

1st time image will be loaded for preview purpose in `iframe`

2nd time image metadata such as width, height will be fetched with same path

**Below image shows 2 times loading same image:**

[image]

in both the call 8.9kB,8.6kB  will be loaded i want to avoid that.

**Question:** I want to calculate `image` aspect ratio with single load of image. 2 calls i need to avoid

**Note:** i want iframe based solution

**Here is demo:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/rNLWJWE?editors=1010

**For reproducing:** we need to disable cache

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The way you asked your question is very frustrating because you have created arbitrary "limitations" (eg. iframe, disabled cache) but don't describe why those limitations are necessary. Looking at your code it's clear that you don't have much experience working in the web/javascript, so it would be really nice if you told us *what* you needed as opposed to *how* to do it. We could probably come up with a much better solution for you.

Anyhow, to answer your question the way you asked... what you need to do is load the resource ONCE outside of an image tag or iframe (in memory), base64 encode the result, and use the encoded data for both the iframe src and the image src. Here's the pseudocode:

```
// this first line will load the image
const imageData = fetchImageAsDataUrl('http://path-to-your-image');
// these next two lines use the existing image data from above
// you will see two entries in the "network" tab with urls like "data:image/jpeg..."
// but there was no additional data transferred across the internet
iframe.src = imageData;
img.src = imageData;
const dimensions = getImgDimensions(img)
```

If you look at the network tab, you will see that only one image is transferred over the internet (the first circle). The next two circled entries happen because the iframe/img src attributes are set, but the data was not loaded over the internet (notice how the url starts with `data:image/jpeg...`).

[image: network tab]

Here's the codepen:

https://codepen.io/DesignByOnyx/pen/gOMKYzL?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The browser is generally speaking smart enough to not fetch the same asset twice from the server, this is called caching. The checkmark Disable cache in your devtools is checked, meaning it will not use cache. This can be useful while developing but you can trust that people generally will not disable cache.

I also don't see the same behaviour on the codepen.

Comment: whatever you said might be correct but i want to solve it programetically

Comment: In the codepen shared, when clicking View Image button, the 300.jpg image appears only once for me.

Comment: please disable cache so that it will show up 2 times

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would be able to achieve this using an iframe is if you have control over the domain it is loading or there are means by which you can enable [cross origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). That way you will be able to access the DOM contents of the iframe and retrieve the needed information from the image element in there.

Another solution is to avoid using iframe in the first place which doesn't make much sense in the example you have given, but you've said you prefer it to stay that way.

And still worth mentioning, as stated in the other answer, the browser will most likely not fetch the image twice anyway so you don't need to worry about that.